# Android Layout - Listview or something else

Tags: android, android-layout, listview

I need to build a layout like the one in the provided screenshot.  It needs to show a list of products with list of product parts within each product.

There could be many products and a product can have 0 or more parts.

User can scroll up and down to view them.

User can also long-tap on a product or part to invoke a pop-up menu for adding a part (such as "Add Part").  The pop-up menu should be invokable on both Part and Product.

User can also expand/colaps Product to show/hide parts (this is preferable to have)

[image]

I an fairly new to Android and on first look, to me this appears to be a ListView (of parts) within a ListView (of products).  But I am not sure if that is the best way to do it.

I am looking for recommendation/links how to do this layout.

Comment: Have a look at [`ExpandableListView`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ExpandableListView.html).

Comment: No, but I wil take  a look.  Thank you

Comment: Even though ExpandableListView seems to be the best option it may not prove beneficial for all your needs. If there's such a case you can even create a custom Expandale ListView style using this library in your  custom list_item layout : https://github.com/traex/ExpandableLayout

Than use Custom Adapter to fill your ListView.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In android It's called [ExpandableListView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ExpandableListView.html)

You can try this tutorial:

http://www.androidhive.info/2013/07/android-expandable-list-view-tutorial/

It also has a sample to download.

Comment: Thanks, I will take a look.  Never heard of it before.